# Mysql check if column contains a number after a specific string

Tags: mysql

I have millions of records in mysql database. My table structure is as follows:

Table name: Records

```
ID  Records
53468290    Printing Multiple Photos on One Page
53438718    Printing embedded charts on a full page
53442132    Printing and Page Setup Options
53427822    Printing a Web Page                 36
53462121    Printing a Single Address Label (Or a Page of the Same Label)
53470574    Printing a Single Address Label (Or a Page of the Same Label)
53462164    Printing a Single Address Label (Or a Page of the Same Label)
53433527    Printing a Single Address Label (or a Page of the Same Label)
53442687    Printable  CNC Machining, 1st Edition page 99 al
53442686    Printable  CNC Machining, 1st Edition page 98 555
53442685    Printable  CNC Machining, 1st Edition page 97
53442684    Printable  CNC Machining, 1st Edition page 96
```

I want to delete only those records which have at least one numeric character after the word "page". In other words I want to delete records which contains "page 100" , "page 1", "page 25 L" , "page 25 5"and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP`:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE Records REGEXP '\\b[Pp]age\\s+\\d';
```

The above is for MySQL 8+, for earlier versions use: `REGEXP '[[:<:]][Pp]age[[:space:]]+[0-9]'`

Comment: Good Solution! however It doesn't delete the number '36' on the 4th row.

Comment: @OzanSen I missed that `page` may have more than one space between it and a following number.  Check the edit which fixes this.